# InApp Purchase - How to Create a Product Binary

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I wanna implement inApp Purchase in my app. The inApp will remove all ads from app.

Ok, i know how create a inApp in iTunes Connect, and i know how create a store with StoreKit.

The only question i have is: How can i create a binary to remove my ads?

It's a copy of my app, but with no ads? (Duplicate project and remove ads)

Or it's a block with Boolean condition to hide ads? (if userBought == YES hideAds)

I already have the Free and Pro Version of my app available in AppStore, just don't know how to link them, making Pro Version a InApp Purchase of Free Version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do the binary thing, you are not allowed to make any changes to the app binary. You also can't do this since the app binary is located on the app bundle.

You can set a bought property and check that to show the banner/ad or not. You should save this boolean in the keychain so the user can easily acces it.

You can always guide the user to the AppStore to buy the pro version, but you cannot make the free version update it self to the pro version.

Comment: Now i'm redirecting my free user to pro version available in AppStore, as you said. But i think i understand how it works now... and in case of consumable coins for example, when user purchase, i just call method to increment the coins number right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like that mate. If you are releasing two apps then you don't have to use in-app coz you can make one of it as free and other as paid. If you want to use one app with in-app then make sure that you store that in **NSUserDefaults** once the user has purchased the in-app then you can set that in **NSUserDefaults** as well.

So when the user starts your applications just check on **NSUserDefaults** and show ads or doesn't show ads by the saved setting on **NSUserDefaults**

Comment: You should really use the KeyChain for these kind of settings. The `NSUserDefaults` is stored in the document directory in plain text and can accessed by the user and edited with some simple tricks.

Comment: @Ushan87 So using NSUserDefaults, i can setBool:NO forKey:@"showAds" when user bought the pro version, and setBool:YES forKey:@"showAds" when user didn't purchase... right? And same for other non-consumible purchases. But when i register a product in iTunes Connect, they ask me for a binary (storage in Apple Host, or my own host). Is that binary required?

Comment: @rckoenes document directory, can be only accessed by app, or jailbroken devices. And unfortunately nobody if safe from jailbreak users.

Comment: @Thiago or you could edit the backup file. It's just to easy to do and saving it in the keychain will also make it more difficult on failbroken devices.

Comment: @rckoenes I will take a look about keychain in iOS, do u have some good tutorial or example?

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to appending a key isPurchase YES in your NSUserDefaults when you purchase App

```
if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchase"])
    {
         NSLog(@"Enter add start ");

       [[Chartboost sharedChartboost]  showInterstitial];
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize];

}
```